# Using databricks for twtter sentiment analysis - issue running the official tutorial

Tags: apache-spark, twitter, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I am starting to use Databricks and tried to implement one of the official tutorials (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-sentiment-analysis-cognitive-services) from the website. However, I run into an issue - not even sure if I can call it an issue - when I run the second notebook (analysetweetsfromeventhub) then all commands (2nd, 3rd, 4th ...) are officially waiting to run, but never run. See the picture. Any idea what might be? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you cancel a running streaming cell in a notebook attached to a Databricks Runtime cluster, you cannot run any subsequent commands in the notebook. The commands are left in the “waiting to run” state, and you must clear the notebook’s state or detach and reattach the cluster before you can successfully run commands on the notebook.

Note that this issue occurs only when you cancel a single cell; it does not apply when you run all and cancel all cells.

In the meantime, you can do either of the following:

- To remediate an affected notebook without restarting the cluster, go to the notebook’s Clear menu and select Clear State:

[image]

- If restarting the cluster is acceptable, you can solve the issue by turning off idle context tracking. Set the following Spark configuration value on the cluster:

  **spark.databricks.chauffeur.enableIdleContextTracking false**

  Then restart the cluster.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.